# Looping through JSON string returned from webmethod as arraylist in asp.net

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a webmethod that returns a arraylist of Properties details in jquery its returning th result as under

i tried to loop through the data , but all the methods are filed as errors are undefined length in the loops ,

```
{
   "d":[
      {
         "__type":"_Default+Properties",
         "propertyid":"18",
         "state":"TamilNadu",
         "district":"RAMANATHAPURAM",
         "taluk":"KADALADI",
         "villages":"ORIVAYAL",
         "latitude":"9.240044",
         "Longitude":"78.520514"
      },
      {
         "__type":"_Default+Properties",
         "propertyid":"47",
         "state":"TamilNadu",
         "district":"RAMANATHAPURAM ",
         "taluk":"KADALADI ",
         "villages":"A.USILANKULAM",
         "latitude":"9.210131",
         "Longitude":"78.499295"
      },
      {
         "__type":"_Default+Properties",
         "propertyid":"33",
         "state":"TamilNadu",
         "district":"RAMANATHAPURAM ",
         "taluk":"KADALAI",
         "villages":"AAPANOOR",
         "latitude":"9.20585",
         "Longitude":"78.500198"
      },
      {
         "__type":"_Default+Properties",
         "propertyid":"32",
         "state":"TamilNadu",
         "district":"VIRUDUNAGAR ",
         "taluk":"RAJAPALAYAM",
         "villages":"AYAN REDDIAPATTI",
         "latitude":"9.401005",
         "Longitude":"77.613261"
      }
   ]
}
```

this is the JSON result .

Please help me to loop through the JSON result .Thanks in advance. 
Regards,
martin

Comment: what do you mean by "but all the methods are filed as errors are undefined length in the loops"

Comment: I believe you meant all methods failed because of undefined length. Can you share your code snippet for reading the JSON data. Also, you can try out de-serializing the JSON data using pre-defined libraries.

Comment: //$.each(obj.d, function(index, property) {
                    //    alert(property.propertyid);                      
                    //});